# Disable ag-grid row selection while performing action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, ag-grid

I just started working on ag-grid react and am stuck where I want to disable currently selected row on which I am performing some action (sending rest call) and re-enable it after getting 200 OK.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by disabling? changing style , prevent click events ?!!

Comment: Disable mean that particular row shouldn't be selectable until we get 200 ok from server and reenable it.